# Difference between while i < x and for i in range(x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, iterator

It seems to me that the two statements below do the same exact thing in python3.

```
while i < x:
    print("hi")
    i+=1
```

and

```
for i in range(x):
    print("hi")
```

Is there a functional difference that I'm missing here?

If so, in what cases would you use one over the other?

Comment: You use the first when you need to meet a condition and the second when you want to iterate over a sequence.

Comment: Hmm, whether they are equivalent depends on what's the value of `i` before the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Usually ***while*** is used when you don't know exactly when you want to stop.
***For*** loop is used when you know how many times you want to perform something.

For example :
You have a number, every loop you do some calculation and stop only when the result smaller than a given limit, you need tu use ***while*** as you don't know how many time you have to run the function.

In the other hand if you want to go thru n-element of a list, you can use a ***while*** but a ***for*** is more logical as you know the size of the list.

In your example there is no difference (or maybe only based on performances, timeit can give you more information)

***Edit 1***
I tried to do the same function with ***while*** and ***for*** (10000 times the sum of integer from 0 to 15) and ***for*** loop is faster. If you can use it, you should choose this one (there is also less variable to set):

Version ***for***

```
s = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    t = 0
    for j in range(15):
        t += j
print(time.time()-s) => 0.0132s
```

Version ***while***

```
s = time.time()
i = 0
while i < 10000:
    t = 0
    j = 0
    i += 1
    while j < 15:
        t += j
        j += 1

print(time.time()-s) => 0.0202s
```

One important point also... with a ***while*** you can have an infinite loop, with for it's impossible :p

Comment: Strictly it's also possible to have an infinite loop with `for x in y:` - `y` can be a generator that doesn't end.

Comment: You are right :) I never thought about that ! But you probably also need an "incorrect" while in the generator right  ?

Comment: If you substitute `xrange` for `range` (in Python 2 - `range` works like this in Python 3  anyway) you get a slightly faster time. And more efficient memory utilisation.

Comment: The loop would have to have some other way of exiting - even if it's just KeyboardInterrupt! The generator could just yield even numbers, primes, whatever, it doesn't need to end.